Meaning of 'In production' Google refresh token, project needs to be private
I have made a desktop application with an ipwOAuth component of IPWorks 2020. The app just sends mail using a Gmail account. All goes very well but I found out that the refresh token has a lifetime of just one day. I have to mention that the project for my app (https://code.google.com/apis/console#access) is still in ‘Testing’ and not ‘In production’. I believe that when switching to ‘In production’ the lifetime of the refresh token is longer. But what does ‘In production’ means? The project needs to be private. I don’t want to share this app/project with anyone. Any ideas?
